# Can "yellow September sunlight" be considered an Epithet?

Tags: epithets, poetic-devices

> The Laburnum top is silent, quite still
> In the afternoon yellow September sunlight
> A few leaves yellowing, all its seeds fallen.

In this stanza from the poem 'The Laburnum Top' by Ted Hughes, can "afternoon yellow September sunlight" be considered an epithet?

Comment: I would include 'afternoon' as a part of that, rather than being "in the afternoon / yellow September sunlight".

Comment: @Weather I have edited my question to add it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering if 'afternoon yellow' is intended as a compound adjective. If not, I'd expect 'In the yellow September afternoon sunlight'. Be that as it may, an epithet needs a separate head noun, which disqualifies 'yellow September sunlight' here.

Comment: Most likely the four-word sequence "afternoon yellow September sunlight" has *never* been used by any native Anglophone independently of Hughes' cited usage here. And it may be just a personal position, but I don't think you can call some expression an "epithet" unless it's got at least *some* kind of "established currency". A syntactically "quirky" line from a poem doesn't meet that criterion.

Comment: It's a Clancian hint for red October sunlight in evenings still surrounding  us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can "yellow September sunlight" be considered an Epithet?

I do not think so. The phrase does not seem to fit the OED definition of "epithet".

> 1.a. **An adjective indicating some quality or attribute which the speaker or writer regards as characteristic of the person or thing described.**
>
> 1863   ‘G. Eliot’ Romola I. v. 94   *Hollow, empty—is the epithet justly bestowed on Fame.*
>
> 2. **A significant appellation.** *[to which I would add, "a name, nickname, or title.]*
>
> 1728   J. Morgan Compl. Hist. Algiers I. vi. 201   *He assumed the proud Epithet of Sultan or Monarch of Tunis and all Barbary.*
>
> 1862   B. Brodie Psychol. Inq. II. iv. 129   *We..employ the French term of ennui, for want of an equally appropriate epithet in English.*